# IE8 and IE9 - Styling after <button> has been clicked

Tags: css, internet-explorer, input

---

Both what Mr. Alien and GionaF said does the trick.

However, in this particular case, we decided to remove the onclick events and disabled="disabled" all together since it didn't really make any sense.

---

I've run into a problem with the `<input type="submit">` element in IE8 and 9.

It looks fine, normal, hover and active states. But after the button has been clicked, the text get's some sort of drop shadow along with a grey color which I can't seem to override.

[image: Image of the issue]

I have a feeling that it might be the onclick events causing this, but can it be fixed through CSS?

Html for the buttons:

```
<input class="button" type="submit" id="CancelButton" name="CancelButton" value="Avbryt" onclick="window.setTimeout( disableButtons, 1 ); return true;" />
<input class="defaultbutton" type="submit" id="PublishButton" name="PublishButton" value="some_ez_publish_code" onclick="window.setTimeout( disableButtons, 1 ); return true;" />
```

The CSS (lot's of classnames, leaving them out):

```
background-image: none;
background: url(../images/btn-sprite-large.png) 0px 0px no-repeat;
border: 0;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: 900;
height: 32px;
line-height: 26px;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #d12015;
width: 120px;
```

Comment: remove text shadow for IE or set some filter

Comment: it seems you are disabling the buttons after clicking, so browser will add top priority style for disabled input elements which you cannot override. simply add this CSS:  input[disabled="disabled"]{text-shadow:none !important;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you're disabling the buttons after click ( function `disableButtons` ). To change the text's grey color (default for disabled) you can use:

```
.button[disabled], .button:disabled {
    color:#fff;
}​
```

Then, as Mr. Alien said, you've to find a way to target ie (probably with [conditional comments](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/)) and switch from `text-shadow` to `filter`:

```
.ie .button {
    text-shadow:none;
    filter:/* etc */
}
```

Comment: Both what Mr. Alien and GionaF said does the trick.

However, in this particular case, we decided to remove the onclick events and disabled="disabled" all together since it didn't really make any sense.

Comment: How come i know `filter:/* etc */`   what is etc ?????????????? You could enter proper value also instead of etc. Plz enter proper value, else its confusing.

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird please look at the specs:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533086(v=vs.85).aspx AND
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532985(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

IE has problem with `text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #d12015;`, so you need to use proprietary property instead

```
filter:DropShadow(Color=#d12015, OffX=1, OffY=0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the browser styles for disabled buttons in IE, but you could wrap your button like this:

```
<div class="button-wrap">
    <a class="button" disabled="disabled"><span>My button</span></a>
    <span class="visible-text">My button</span>
</div>
```

Then position and style visible-text as you want. Something like this:

```
.visible-text {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: green; /* or whatever... */
}
```

Using visibility: hidden on the default button text keeps the width of the button so you can position there the same text without any problem.

```
a.button span {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Please try it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/fnwjT/47/